# Laravel 5.7: Argument 1 passed to

Tags: php, laravel-5, namespaces, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-5.7

I implemented the maatwebiste(export to excel) and trying to improve it where the admin can choose "From Date:" to "To Date:" to export.

When I submit the form, I'm encountering error `"Argument 1 passed to App\Exports\PostExport::to_date() must be an instance of App\Exports\date, string given, called in "`

NOTE: I used var_dump to check if it has value

Question: How do I pass my values to my PostExport file?(my export to excel file)

**View**

```
<form action="{{ route('export.excel') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <p>To: <input type="text" id="to_datepicker" name="to_datepicker"></p>
                <p>From: <input type="text" id="from_datepicker" name="from_datepicker"></p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Export</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function excel(Request $request)
    {
        $to_datepicker = $request->to_datepicker;
        $from_datepicker = $request->from_datepicker;
        echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($to_datepicker);
            var_dump($from_datepicker);
        echo "</pre>";
        // die;

        // Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) { 

        //  // Call writer methods here
        //  Excel::selectSheets('title')->load();


        // });

        return (new PostExport)->to_date($to_datepicker)->from_date($from_datepicker)->download('invoices.xlsx');

    }
```

**PostExport**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Responsable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
// use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;

class PostExport implements FromQuery, Responsable
{
    use Exportable;
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    // private $fileName = 'invoices.xlsx';

    public function to_date(date $to)
    {
        $this->to = $to;

        return $this;

    }
    public function from_date(date $from)
    {
        $this->from = $from;

        return $this;
    }


    public function query()
    {
        // return Post::query()->whereYear('created_at', $this->year)
        //                    ->orWhere('created_at',$this->month);

        return Post::query()->whereBetween('created_at',[$this->to,$this->from]);
    }
    // public function collection()
    // {

    //     return Post::all();
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
public function to_date(date $to)
```

What is `date` here? There is no `date` class by default in PHP. In this case probably you want to remove `date` from here completely or replace with `string`:

```
public function to_date(string $to)
```

Comment: Actually I already did that, yes its working but the file is corrupted. "Excel cannot open the file '...'  because the file format or the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and the file extension is matches the file extension"

Comment: Yes, but this is completely other issue. In question you asked about argument error.